# How can I sort out new lines in an older text file and overwrite to the other text file

Tags: php

I'm receiving data by using php curl and saving them to a text file.
It is automatically refreshing and writing data on old text.

so, I tried to write a function that will sort out new* lines in an old* text file, and will save new* text file. But I falled apart. What can I do for it?

> old text file

```
line6) 6666666666
line5) 5555566666
line4) 4444444444
line3) 3333333333
line2) 2222222222
line1) 1111111111
```

> new curl data

```
line9) 9999999999
line8) 8888888888
line7) 7777777777
line6) 6666666666
line5) 5555566666
line4) 4444444444
line3) 3333333333
line2) 2222222222
line1) 1111111111
```

> should be writen new lines to new text file

```
line9) 9999999999
line8) 8888888888
line7) 7777777777
```

---

the dublicate data that I dont want to use.
here is an example that I already use. (Please read all line numbers carefully)

```
line9) 9999999999
line8) 8888888888
line7) 7777777777
line6) 6666666666
line5) 5555566666
line4) 4444444444
line3) 3333333333
line2) 2222222222
line1) 1111111111
line6) 6666666666
line5) 5555566666
line4) 4444444444
line3) 3333333333
line2) 2222222222
line1) 1111111111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if your still looking for an answer, but that's what I came with. If I properly understood what you need, it will do the job...

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$newcontent1 = array(); // set new array for future content
$newcontent2 = array(); // set new array for future content

$array1 = array('9999999999', '8888888888', '0000000000', '6666666666', '5555555555', '4444444444', '3333333333', '2222222222', '1111111111');
$array = array(0 => '9999999999', 1 => '8888888888', 2 => '0000000000', 3 => '6666666666', 4 => '5555555555', 5 => '4444444444', 6 => '3333333333', 7 => '2222222222', 8 => '1111111111');
// 2 different output, but it doesn't really matter, just for testing...

echo"Array is :<br />";
print_r($array);
echo"<br /><br />";

echo"File content :<br />";

$file = "test.inc.txt"; // a regulat txt file similar to your 'old text file'
$filec = file_get_contents($file); // get file in a var

print_r($filec);  // only for checking purpose -> remove it when prod mode

echo"<br /><br />";

foreach ($array as $value)
    { // parse array to get the value of each entry
    if( !in_array($value, $newcontent1) ) { array_push($newcontent1, "$value\n"); // we push value to temp array #1
    echo"( value of array entry -> $value )<br />"; // only for checking purpose -> remove it when prod mode
    } else { /* do nothing */ }
    }

echo"<br /><br />";
echo"New temp content 1:<br />";
print_r($newcontent1); // only for checking purpose -> remove it when prod mode
echo"<br /><br />";

$fp = fopen("test.inc.txt","r"); // we open file

    while($line = fgets($fp)) { // parse file data to get each line
        $line = trim($line);
        if( !in_array($line, $array1) ) { array_push($newcontent2, "$line\n"); echo"( value of file line -> $line )<br />"; } else { /* do nothing */ }
    }

echo"<br /><br />";
echo"New temp content 2:<br />";
print_r($newcontent2); // only for checking purpose -> remove it when prod mode
echo"<br /><br />";

echo"New content (sorted ASC):<br />";

// *important part below* -> we combine the 2 temp arrays into one with unique value
$newcontent = array_unique(array_merge($newcontent1, $newcontent2));

sort($newcontent); // rsort($newcontent); for desc order

file_put_contents('output.txt', $newcontent); // we write new content of array to file
// here, you may want to had checking upon creation of new file

print_r($newcontent);

echo"<br /><br />done !";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you OldPadawan. Do you have any opinion for this question? > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620072/removing-duplicate-lines-from-multiple-2-text-files-in-php