# Removing duplicate lines from multiple (2) text files in PHP

Tags: php, python, file, curl

I have 2 .txt files.
First .txt file is curl data (robot) and it always gets 2000 .txt lines including new ones

and the second .txt file has new data of first .txt file.
I use the second .txt file for the script.

I cant remove dublicates. (I mean I try to get new values according to the old values) so script always use data with new and also old.

***Is there a way to open all the files, remove duplicates and save the lines accordingly to second file?***

**THERE ARE THREE REFRESH EXAMPLES**

> here is FIRST refresh and 2 .txt files

*first .txt file (you should think it has 2000 lines) refresh curl robot*

```
Something here10
Something here9
Something here8
Something here7
Something here6
Something here5
Something here4
Something here3
Something here2
Something here1
```

*second .txt file that i will use*

```
Something here10
Something here9
Something here8
Something here7
Something here6
Something here5
Something here4
Something here3
Something here2
Something here1
```

> here is SECOND refresh and 2 .txt files

*first .txt file (you should think it has 2000 lines) refresh curl bot*

```
Something here14
Something here13
Something here12
Something here11
Something here10
Something here9
Something here8
Something here7
Something here6
Something here5
```

*second .txt file that i will use*

```
Something here14
Something here13
Something here12
Something here11
```

> here is THIRD refresh and 2 .txt files

*first .txt file (you should think it has 2000 lines) refresh curl bot*

```
Something here16
Something here15
Something here14
Something here13
Something here12
Something here11
Something here10
Something here9
Something here8
Something here7
```

*second .txt file that i will use*

```
Something here16
Something here15
```

**EDIT:
I posted two new refresh**

> here is FOURTH refresh and 2 .txt files

*first .txt file (you should think it has 2000 lines) refresh curl bot*

```
Something here20
Something here19
Something here18
Something here17
Something here16
Something here15
Something here14
Something here13
Something here12
Something here11
```

*second .txt file that i will use*

```
Something here20
Something here19
Something here18
Something here17
```

> here is FIFTH refresh and 2 .txt files

*first .txt file (you should think it has 2000 lines) refresh curl bot*

```
Something here24
Something here23
Something here22
Something here21
Something here20
Something here19
Something here18
Something here17
Something here16
Something here15
```

*second .txt file that i will use*

```
Something here24
Something here23
Something here22
Something here21
```

Comment: @rizier123 Rizier123 is here?

Comment: not that clear for me... do you need to combine all files into one new with no duplicate ? or just combine every time `first.txt + second.txt = new-with-no-duplicate.txt` ?

Comment: @oldpadawan no, only first.txt and second.txt. I use only second text. first one is robot. I cant touch it. output is second text

Comment: still don't get it... combine FIRST refresh + SECOND refresh into one new file with no duplicate ? can you show an simple example of what is expected at the end ? ie: 1st data / 2nd data = final data

Comment: @mackprogramsalot can you please give me your email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to keep this as high level as possible but in essence push each line onto an array and then use array_unique to remove duplicates:

```
    $line_array = array();
    $files = getFiles();
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $lines = $file->getAllLines();
        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
            $line_array[] = $line;
        }
    }
    $without_duplicates = array_unique($line_array);
```

Comment: @mackprogramsalot $file1 = @file("first.txt"); and $file2 = @file("second.txt"); ???

Comment: getAllLines() returns all the lines of a file
getFiles() gets the files

maybe this type of pseudocode is frowned upon on stack overflow?

Comment: @mackprogramsalot how to i add .txt here? file_get_contents?

Answer (score 1):

> (reading and interpreting comments) I think you need the following code, using [PHP array push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array1 = array('here9', 'here8', 'here7', 'here6', 'here5', 'here4', 'here3', 'here2', 'here1');
$array2 = array('here4', 'here3', 'here2', 'here1');

echo"Array 1:<br />"; // just checking -> will be removed
print_r($array1); // just checking -> will be removed

echo"<br /><br />Array 2:<br />"; // just checking -> will be removed
print_r($array2); // just checking -> will be removed

echo"<br /><br />"; // will be removed

$newarray = array(); // create new empty array to receive new data

foreach ($array1 as $value) { /* parse array */

// here, we'll make use of PHP array_push
if( !in_array($value, $array2) ) { // if value is not in 2nd array

array_push($newarray, $value); // we add to new array we created

} else { /* do nothing */ }
    }

echo"New array with duplicate removed:<br />"; // just checking -> will be removed
print_r($newarray); // just checking -> will be removed

file_put_contents('output.txt', $newarray); // we write new content of array to file

?>
```